# Asynchronous Maps Not Loading?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a Google Maps v3 Asynchronous map into my site, and have it nearly identical to the how to. No map loads on the page though! Does anyone see anything wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.7870,-86.1023),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
```

and

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

The CSS for this page is very simple:

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Look at your javascript errors `Error: google is not defined`.  Fix that then: `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The "sensor" parameter specified in the request must be set to either "true" or "false".`  Fix that and the map appears.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues.

1. move this line

   `google.maps.visualRefresh = true;`

   to the begin of `initialize` . When you load the API asynchronously, `google` is still undefined at the time when this line will be executed(*your debugger should have told you this*), this error will prevent all following instructions from executing.
2. `script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' +
     'callback=initialize';`

   add an ampersand after `false`

Comment: This is very informative and helpful. Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote you, but I need more reputation first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sometines is better go directly to the source and not use google :)

Yo can have a look the source code that they are using and learn. After that you can google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

In this example they use syncronous load for the google maps library.

You could like to load asyncronous then use this way:

· First add the div and your initialize function:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 480px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.7870,-86.1023),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

Note: You don't need to use google.maps.visualRefresh = true; anymore as google say here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics

· Second place the script for asyncronous load and the head or before the last line before the en of the   mark. This will make a little fast speed load of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```